# How to stream audio files without giving absolute path

Tags: javascript, php, html, audio

Is there anyway to stream an audio file without giving `complete path` of the file.

For example whenever we tried to play `mp3` file with HTML5 Audio tag or With javascript, then i have to supply complete path of mp3 file something like this

```
<audio controls>
  <source src="http://example.com/file/hello_name.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

So, i think can we supply an `id` of the mp3 file instead of `complete path` of the file which should be something like this:

```
<audio controls>
  <source src="http://example.com/stream.php?file_id=111" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

Comment: Do you use any sort of database for this? If yes, then store file paths in database with unique ids and then retrieve them on stream.php using the id of the file

Comment: Yes, i am doing same thing what you are saying, but how it will stream..Can you give a example ?

Comment: Check the answer. It will give you a hint how to achieve this in php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your stream.php file will look like this:

```
<?php
    // Say you hava a table "file_paths" with two columns file_id and file_path
    $sql = $pdo->prepare("SELECT FROM file_paths WHERE file_id = ?");
    $sql->bindValue(1, $_GET['file_id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $sql->execute();
    $fetch = $sql->fetchObject();

    // retrieve file path using its id
    $path = $fetch->file_path;
    header("Location: " . $path);
?>
```

And then on target page, add the player by passing file_id to stream.php like this:

```
<audio controls>
  <source src="stream.php?file_id=123" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

Answer (score 0):

Typically you'd have `stream.php` deliver the binary data (e.g. for file_id == 111 as in your example) by sending the correct headers with [header()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) and the data with [readfile()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) provided that you have a relation between `file_id` and a physical file in a database or something similar.

Please be careful with `readfile()`, though, and be aware that it will just output whatever it's told to, so make sure your application doesn't allow someone to tell it to output other stuff like config files with database passwords and such.